# Help verifying this "simple" Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

**Example 1.2.3** Show that if $c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants then

$ y = (c_1 + c_2 x) e^{-x} + 2x - 4 \quad $ **(1.2.7)**

is a solution of

$ y'' + 2y' + y = 2x \quad $ **(1.2.8)**

on $(\infty,-\infty)$.

**Solution** Differentiating **(1.2.7)** twice yields

$ y' = -(c_1 + c_2 x) e^{-x} + c_2 e^{-x} + 2 $

and

$ y'' = (c_1 + c_2 x) e^{-x} - 2 c_2 e^{-x} $

########################################

This problem was from the book [*Elementary Differential Equations* by *William F. Trench*, page $9$](https://scholarcommons.usf.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1007&context=oa_textbooks).

I differentiated $y'$ to get

$ y'' = (c_1 + c_2 x) e^{-x} - c_2 e^{-x} $.

Can someone please explain to me where the $2$ in front of the $ c_2 e^{-x} $ term came from?

Comment: There’s a mistake. There shouldn’t be a $2$

Comment: @marwalix : There is no mistake, the 2 is correct, there are contributions from both terms in the first derivative that contain $c_2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is elementary,

$$y''= (-(c_1 + c_2 x) e^{-x} + c_2 e^{-x} + 2)'=\color{green}{-c_2e^{-x}}+(c_1+c_2x)e^{-x}\color{green}{-c_2e^{-x}}. $$

Answer (score 0):

In general you have
$$
(xf(x))'=xf'(x)+f(x)\\
(xf(x))''=xf''(x)+2f'(x)
$$
or even more general
$$
(f(x)g(x))'=f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)\\
(f(x)g(x))'=f''(x)g(x)+2f'(x)g'(x)+f(x)g''(x)\\
$$
If you extend this, you get a formula with binomial coefficients
$$
(f(x)g(x))^{(n)}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}f^{(n-k)}(x)g^{(k)}(x)
$$
These all are extensions or versions of the Leibniz product rule of differentiation.